# PL/SQL numeric or value error when converting to number

Tags: oracle, plsql

I'm busy with a little PL/SQL program and i got stuck when i got the error "*numeric or value error*"
I'm trying to convert a `varchar2` that consists of only numbers to a number using TO_NUMBER().

I'm relatively new to PL/SQL, so i'm thinking it's something really dumb :)

This is my code:

```
set serveroutput on
DECLARE    
vRearranged varchar(50);    
iNumber number(38);    
BEGIN    
vRearranged := 3214282912345698765432161100;    
iNumber := To_Number(vRearranged,   50);    
dbms_output.put_line(iNumber);    
END;
```

could anyone help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second argument of To_number() is the format picture, which should be a string.

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions211.htm#SQLRF06140

Answer (score 0):

DECLARE

vRearranged varchar2(50);

iNumber number(38);

BEGIN

vRearranged := 3214282912345698765432161100;

iNumber := To_Number(vRearranged);

dbms_output.put_line(iNumber);

END;